# Formal definition for a specific type of concrete noun involving entities?

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns

I am looking specifically for a list of proper concrete nouns that represent entities or categorizations of entities that can be used in place of the proper noun, however this is not what I am asking for...

What I am asking for is if there is a specific definition to this type of concrete noun.  If I had such a definition then it would greatly aid my search for such a list or help me to build it.

Examples of the type of noun I am looking for if my description doesn't make sense:

- Bear
- Dolphin
- Bigfoot
- Alien
- Hippie
- Shakespeare (the person)
- Tree

So you can see that by "entity" I mean a word that directly identifies or categorically identifies a living being of any kind, fictional or otherwise.

Is there such a term for this very specific type of concrete noun?

Comment: Generally, the term _entity_ is not restricted to living beings. What you probably want is _animate noun_. It's all laid out very nicely in Frawley's [_Linguistic Semantics_](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=uyavMKhIfV8C&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=frawley+linguistic+semantics), specifically in [Chapter 3: "Entities"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/frawleyentities.pdf)

Comment: @JohnLawler - if you change this comment to an answer, I shall upvote it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  Please convert this comment to an answer so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(by request)*

Generally, the term *entity* is not restricted to living beings.

What you probably want is *animate noun*.

It's all laid out very nicely in Frawley's [Linguistic Semantics](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=uyavMKhIfV8C&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=frawley%20linguistic%20semantics), specifically in [Chapter 3: "Entities"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/frawleyentities.pdf).